# Use a webpage as the UI in a C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, html

I'm building a C# desktop app with a simple UI. Due to my familiarity with HTML/CSS, and a previous web-based iteration of a very similar app, it would be ideal if I could re-use some existing HTML/CSS pages I have as the UI for this new desktop app.

Is that do-able with C#? Can anyone show a simple example of using an HTML/CSS page as the UI of a C# desktop application?

Comment: What do you mean by desktop application? Do you mean WinForms? Is asp.net not an option?

Comment: I mean an application that runs on an end-users machine. It is *not* a web application.

Comment: yes in that case it is a desktop application; in C# you can create a win forms or wpf application.

Comment: Why could a web application not run on an end-users machine?

Answer (score 22):

Other answers are dated, new good options:

- [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) + [Electron-Edge](https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge) - is the way to go for a new Electron app that communicates to a .NET backend (a DLL). Widely used and supported.
- [Neutronium](https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/Neutronium) - best for already-written .NET WPF apps that need a HTML UI. Requires using Vue. Less popular and less supported.

Answer (score 7):

CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) is a good way to embed chromium, but you still need a web server. Take a look at http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/ to alternative for IIS.

Comment: For desktop application, if we using CefSharp, is we still need a web server ?

Comment: @Eric K. Yes, you still need a web a server. You could create your own web server and embed in your application, take a look at this post.
https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server

Answer (score 5):

You can use `WebBrowser`  control to add Web browser functionality to your application.

You can create your own html(s) and set your `WebBrowser` control to display those pages. You can navigate by clicking hyperlinks or by using keyboard shortcuts to move backward and forward through navigation history. By default, you can access additional browser functionality through the right-click shortcut menu

You can even manage those pages centrally (for e.g. on LAN) and all clients on LAN can connect to this central location. This way you can modify pages centrally.

Check a walkthrough on MSDN:

[How to: Add Web Browser Capabilities to a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666.aspx)

Comment: Can you handle events from those pages, like button clicks and such?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Yes you can call control events and script methods implemented in the pages from your client application code.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this poses the question of "why have an app instead of just making the whole thing webbased and run in the browser of the user's preference?"

Comment: @vincent Most desktop apps do things that involve communicating with the host OS in a way that web pages are expressly not permitted to do for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use a Chromium-based control - [DotNetBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser). This control provides wide interactivity options, like DOM manipulation and DOM events, which can be useful in your case.

In addition, there is an article that demonstrates how to use a web page as HTML UI in a C# desktop application: https://www.infoq.com/articles/html-desktop-net

Affiliation disclosure: I work with the team, which created DotNetBrowser.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a Web Browser control to a forms application to show your page. But this will need to be remotely hosted as the code will not be able to execute locally, except if you listen for the specific links in c# and then perform the actions.

You could also try your hand at WPF which is a new technology to create good looking gui's with mark-up much like html, which you'll pick up pretty quickly with your html experience.

Comment: WPF has been around for 10+ years already. Microsoft made it [open source](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf) and is porting it to .NET Core. Wondering if that also means cross-platform. Pretty interesting developments.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither WinForms or WPF is sufficiently like HTML/CSS to be of that kind of use. You'll be able to reuse the layout-concepts and art of course. And, with WPF being the closest thing to it, you might even keep a lot of the code-behind code.

But the short answer is: No

Comment: You can add fully functional browser capabilities in windows applications. **Almost all common browsers capable of running on windows are Windows applications**.

Comment: @ukhardy: I'd dare say ALL browsers capable of running on windows are Windows applications... What's your point?

Comment: @ukhardy: +1 for remembering Lynx (http://www.delorie.com/web/lynxview.html) :) But hardly worth considering in this case.